# Ban command won't work, no error message discord.js

Tags: discord.js

My ban command won't work, it worked a few days ago but not working now and I can't figure out why. I just started coding so I really don't know what to try, if anyone could help me it would be much appreciated! I'm not getting an error in my console so I really have no clue what to do.
Here's my code:

```
if (cmd === `${prefix}ban`) {
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("You do not have permission to do that.");
        const user = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (!user) return message.reply("Please specify someone you want to ban. **.ban <user> [reason]**");
        if(user.id === message.author.id) return message.reply("You cannot ban yourself.");
        const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).ban({reason: reason});
 
        const banmessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#00aaaa")
        .setDescription(`${user} has been banned. Reason: **${reason != "" ? reason : "-"}**`);
        message.channel.send(banmessage);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use a collection when you're trying to ban one person. (**cache is not needed**)

This should do the trick:

```
message.guild.member(user.id).ban({reason: "bad"});
```

Reference:

[GuildMember#ban](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban) Method for more insight.